# How to set a NSTimer with a changing delay?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to set a timer with a constantly changing delay which is stored in a variable. How would I do this, if I set a timer within a timer to update the delay it doesn't work at all.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't have a repeating timer. Use a run once timer, and when it completes/runs, create another timer with the new delay.

Or... as @Steve Wilford noted in his answer, use setFireDate: on NSTimer. From the docs "Adjusting the firing time of a single timer would likely incur less expense than creating multiple timer objects, scheduling each one on a run loop, and then destroying them."

Answer (score 1):

In your class interface use

```
@interface YourClass : SuperClass <Delegates> {
    NSTimer *yourTimer;
    NSInteger delay;
}
```

And when you set your timer make sure you set

```
delay = 1.0;
yourTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:delay target:self selector:@selector(methodToCall) userInfo:nil repeats:false];
```

And finally in your `methodToCall`

```
-(void)methodToCall {
   // Do stuff and reset timer with delay variable

   yourTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:delay target:self selector:@selector(methodToCall) userInfo:nil repeats:false];
}
```

This means that the timer will have to run down to start running again with a new delay so this might not exactly be the solution you are after if you want something more instantaneous, but changing `delay` will mean that when the timer runs down it will begin again with your new delay

This also still allows you to call `[yourTimer invalidate]` and not have repeating timers with no pointer

Hope that helps, or maybe will point you to the solution you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [`setFireDate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000319-BBCCEHJG) method of `NSTimer` will help?

Note that it is a "relatively expensive" operation so you should consider if this is actually what you want to be doing.

Comment: I like this. Also note: "Adjusting the firing time of a single timer would likely incur less expense than creating multiple timer objects, scheduling each one on a run loop, and then destroying them"... so actually you're answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

bandejapaisa has the right idea, but you might need to create the new timer from the main thread. Use:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#> waitUntilDone:<#(BOOL)#>]
```

to create the new timer.

Comment: I'm slightly confused about that. So does that method directly call the animation or something else?

Comment: No, use that call to call a method to create a new timer with your new time.  You call it when your old timer expires.

Comment: The NSTimer will fire on the same runloop you posted it on originally, so you don't need to use performSelectorOnMainThread.